# Lendo lista de inteiros a partir de um arquivo binário

Tags: python

Preciso ler os 10 milhões de números inteiros que estão em [um arquivo binário](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9BqHJmaBEVTVTM4d29ELXVZZGc) e colocá-los numa lista. O programa não dá erro, porém as leituras dão uns números estranhos:

main:

```
nome_arqivo="randomnumbers.bin"
lista=[]
try:
    arquivo=open(nome_arqivo,"rb")
except IOError:
    print("Erro na abertura do arquivo")


#for x in arquivo:
    #lista.append(arquivo.read(4))

for x in range(10000000):
   lista.append(arquivo.read(4))

for item in lista:
    print(item)
```

O final da printagem sai desse jeito:

```
b'\x00\xca\x82\x05'

b'\x00Y\x88\x08'

b'\x00\xb1\xe4\x12'

b'\x00\xb6j\x0e'

b''

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Pode colocar um trecho do arquivo que possui os números? Aqui não abriu o link que passou. E por quê diz que saiu números estranhos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gerando arquivo com `128 bytes` com dados aleatórios para teste, o que representa `32` números inteiros de `4 bytes`:

```
$ head -c 128 < /dev/urandom > randomnumbers.bin
```

Arquivo gerado:

```
$ xxd randomnumbers.bin 
0000000: 300c 54ea 4023 8592 267c 0dc9 f961 0a6d  0.T.@#..&|...a.m
0000010: d0d6 cef3 950e 39ac 8422 5671 c1a2 2546  ......9.."Vq..%F
0000020: ea5a b0e5 cb00 9fb5 40e5 cb7b 849e fb36  .Z......@..{...6
0000030: d64e 77f8 0351 866c 4f2c 824b c98b 82a5  .Nw..Q.lO,.K....
0000040: 7421 e0d1 626a 2cdd 090e 69a4 0894 01bf  t!..bj,...i.....
0000050: 37a0 0405 cdbc 57f2 fa4f 1e78 89c1 f2b5  7.....W..O.x....
0000060: c8eb 2c63 4c13 2e47 d59b 234d b951 41df  ..,cL..G..#M.QA.
0000070: 1d65 52a7 51c9 240e 2426 4f55 a6c9 2cfb  .eR.Q.$.$&OU..,.
```

**Solução #1**: utilizando o módulo [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html):

```
import struct

lista=[]

with open( "randomnumbers.bin", "rb") as arq:
    for num in iter( lambda: arq.read(4), b'' ):
        lista.append( struct.unpack( 'i', num )[0] )

print(lista)
```

Saída:

```
[-363590608, -1836768448, -921863130, 1829396985, -204548400, -1405546859, 1901470340, 1176871617, -441427222, -1247870773, 2076960064, 922459780, -126398762, 1820741891, 1266822223, -1518171191, -773840524, -584291742, -1536618999, -1090415608, 84189239, -229131059, 2015252474, -1242381943, 1663888328, 1194201932, 1294179285, -549367367, -1487772387, 237291857, 1431250468, -80950874]
```

**Solução #2**: Utilizando [NumPy Arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy):

```
import numpy as np

with open( "randomnumbers.bin", "rb") as arq:
    lista = np.fromfile( arq, dtype=np.int32 ).tolist()

print(lista)
```

Saída:

```
[-363590608, -1836768448, -921863130, 1829396985, -204548400, -1405546859, 1901470340, 1176871617, -441427222, -1247870773, 2076960064, 922459780, -126398762, 1820741891, 1266822223, -1518171191, -773840524, -584291742, -1536618999, -1090415608, 84189239, -229131059, 2015252474, -1242381943, 1663888328, 1194201932, 1294179285, -549367367, -1487772387, 237291857, 1431250468, -80950874]
```

**Solução #3:** Utilizando o método `.from_bytes()` *(Somente Python 3)*

```
lista=[]

with open( "randomnumbers.bin", "rb") as arq:
    for num in iter( lambda: arq.read(4), b'' ):
        lista.append(int.from_bytes(num, byteorder='little', signed=True))

print(lista)
```

Saída:

```
[-363590608, -1836768448, -921863130, 1829396985, -204548400, -1405546859, 1901470340, 1176871617, -441427222, -1247870773, 2076960064, 922459780, -126398762, 1820741891, 1266822223, -1518171191, -773840524, -584291742, -1536618999, -1090415608, 84189239, -229131059, 2015252474, -1242381943, 1663888328, 1194201932, 1294179285, -549367367, -1487772387, 237291857, 1431250468, -80950874]
```

**Analise Comparativa** *(Python 3)*:

O utilitátio `time` pode ser usado para comparar a eficiência das duas soluções apresentadas ao processar arquivos grandes.

Gerando arquivo com dados aleatórios de `128MB` bytes, o que representa `33.554.432` números inteiros de `4 bytes`:

```
$ head -c 128M < /dev/urandom > randomnumbers.bin
```

**teste.py**:

```
import sys
import struct
import numpy as np

def solucao_struct():
    lista=[]
    with open( "randomnumbers.bin", "rb") as arq:
        for num in iter( lambda: arq.read(4), b'' ):
            lista.append( struct.unpack( 'i', num )[0] )

def solucao_numpy():
    with open( "randomnumbers.bin", "rb") as arq:
        lista = np.fromfile( arq, dtype=np.int32 ).tolist()

def solucao_from_bytes():
    lista=[]
    with open( "randomnumbers.bin", "rb") as arq:
        for num in iter( lambda: arq.read(4), b'' ):
            lista.append(int.from_bytes(num, byteorder='little', signed=True))

if( sys.argv[1] == "--np" ):
    solucao_numpy()
elif( sys.argv[1] == "--struct" ):
    solucao_struct()
elif( sys.argv[1] == "--frombytes" ):
    solucao_from_bytes()
```

Mensurando a Perfomance da solução com NumPy Arrays:

```
$ time python3 teste.py --np

real    0m3.766s
user    0m2.384s
sys     0m1.362s
```

Inteiros Por Segundo (NumPy):

```
(128MB / 4Bytes) / 3.766s = 8909833.2
```

Mensurando a Perfomance da solução com Struct:

```
$ time python3 teste.py --struct

real    0m38.200s
user    0m36.700s
sys     0m1.411s
```

Inteiros Por Segundo (Struct):

```
(128MB / 4Bytes) / 38.2s = 878388.2
```

Mensurando a Perfomance da solução com `int.from_bytes()`:

```
$ time python3 teste.py --frombytes

real    2m2.691s
user    2m1.057s
sys     0m1.375s
```

Inteiros Por Segundo (`int.from_bytes()`):

```
(128MB / 4Bytes) / 62.691s = 535235.2
```

Comment: Entre as tuas soluções e a minha que eu encontrei, qual você acha a mais eficiente?

Comment: @Rafael Questões de eficiência é melhor medir do que especular. Algo que pode parecer mais eficiente (por exemplo, por ser de mais baixo nível) pode ser pior do que uma alternativa de mais alto nível.

Comment: @Rafael: Fiz uma edição demonstrando como mensurar a performance das soluções. A solução utilizando `NymPy` arrays se mostrou `12x` mais eficiente que a solução com `struct.unpack()`

Comment: @PabloAlmeida: Ver Edição.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado por me apresentar essa bibioteca numpy. Se antes com a minha implementação tava demorando 10 segundos pra le os 10 milhoes de ints agora ele tá lendo tudo em 0.2 segundos. Além disso, acho que essa numpy vai me apresentar outras ótimas soluções pro meu trabalho que to fazendo. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Pessoas, consegui achar o erro. Tô acostumado com c/c++ e lá não há necessidade de converter bytes pra inteiro ao ler um arquivo binário. Aqui é necessário. Abaixo o código corrigido:

```
import time

nome_arqivo="randomnumbers.bin"
lista=[]
try:
    arquivo=open(nome_arqivo,"rb")
except IOError:
    print("Erro na abertura do arquivo")

for x in range(10000000):
    lista.append(int.from_bytes(arquivo.read(4), byteorder='little'))

for item in lista:
    time.sleep(4)
    print(item)
```

Comment: Lembrando que `int.from_bytes()` é um dos novos métodos do `int` no `Python 3` e não é compatível com o `Python 2`.

Comment: Acredito que toda solução que utiliza um laço `for` sempre será lenta em relação ao metodo `fromfile()` de uma `NumPy Array`.